# How do I convert picturebox.click event into a button.click event

Tags: vb.net, drawing, directcast

I'm trying to have two options to draw a border around a picture box.
I can click on the picturebox to highlight but now would like to be able to use a button to do the same thing.

```
 Private Sub imgLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgLabel.Click

Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics, BorderBounds, Color.Orange, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

If Not (HighLightededPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
    HighLightededPictureBox.Invalidate()
End If

'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox  
HighLightededPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
```

When I try to add a button click I get the Exception Unhandled - System.windows.forms.button to type System.windows.forms.picturebox error.

I have tried to add the button click event after "Handles" which causes the above error.

```
 Private Sub imgLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgLabel.Click, button1.click
```

I'm pretty new to programming and my searching results are turning anything up of value.  I don't fully understand Ctypes/Directcasts.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Ok, so I ended up going with this...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim boxsize As New Size(192, 169)
    Dim recpoint As New Point(0, 0)
    Dim myrectangle As New Rectangle(recpoint, boxsize)
    myrectangle.Inflate(-3, -3)
    Dim G As Drawing.Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    Dim Pen As New Pen(Color.Orange, 5)
    G.DrawRectangle(Pen, myrectangle)
End Sub
```

Seems to be working ok, but requires a lot of manual entry of points.  I have 6 more of these.

Comment: You could use one event, but you'd have to evaluate `sender` to see if is a button or picture box. You cannot cast one to the other.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: ...or if there is just one picturebox you are playing with, use `imgLabel` (assuming thats the picturebox) and dont use `sender` at all.  Also you should do the painting in the Paint event and use the graphics object passed to you rather than `CreateGraphics`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the options.  I don't understand what you mean by evaluating sender but i'll do some searching.

Comment: `TypeOf`, `GetType` and `TryCast` are ways you could do it, but as I said that is in the wrong place, your border wont survive repaints

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    imgLabel_Click(imgLabel, nothing)
End Sub
```